# Spring Data : how to use repository's inner interfaces outside the outer class?

Tags: java, spring, interface, spring-data

When I have lot of repositories interface I usually use a wrapper like this :

```
@Component
public class RepositoryContainer(){

 @Autowired
 public Myrepo1 repo1;

 @Autowired
 public Myrepo2 repo2;
 //and so on....
}
```

Then I use it :

```
@Service
public class Myservice(){

 @Autowired
 RepositoryContainer repos;

 public void service1(){
   repos.repo1.findBy...
 }

}
```

The problem is this way of doing generates many files, since each repository is an interface, so I have same files for repositories as for entities.

To reduce the number of files I tried using nested interfaces :

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryContainer(){

  public interface Myrepo1 extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Long> {
  }

  public interface Myrepo2 extends JpaRepository<Entity2, Long> {
  }
  //and so on...
}
```

Now I am struggle because I can't access my repositories outside the class.
Is there a way to do this :

```
@Service
public class Myservice(){

@Autowired
RepositoryContainer repos;

  public void service1(){
  //I would like to do this :
   repos.Myrepo1.findBy...
  }

}
```

Note that I've already enabled nested discovery repositories in

```
@EnableJpaRepositories( considerNestedRepositories = true )
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: to have access to `RepositoryContainer. Myrepo1`, you need an instance of the `RepositoryContainer` and an instance of the `Myrepo1`. Try to inject by `RepositoryContainer. Myrepo1` type

Comment: @AndrewTobilko an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion with @Cepro0 here my solution :

```
@Repository
public class RepositoryContainer(){

  public interface Myrepo1 extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Long> {
  }

  public interface Myrepo2 extends JpaRepository<Entity2, Long> {
  }
   //I am using an inner bean to get my repositories
  @Component
  public class Container{
    @Autowired
    public Myrepo1 repo1;
    @Autowired 
    public Myrepo2 repo2; 
  }
}
```

Then :

```
@Service
public class Myservice(){

  @Autowired
  RepositoryContainer.Container repos;

  public void service1(){
   repos.repo1.findBy...
  }
}
```

This works perfectly and since today this is how I will proceed for reducing the number of file for each repository's interface and having a clean code because sometimes we need many repositories in a service and we have to inject them one-by-one.

If someone sees some drawbacks, please let me know.

Answer (score 10):

Just turn on parameter `considerNestedRepositories` in `EnableJpaRepositories` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class Application {
    //...
}
```

And then you will be able to inject your 'inner' repo:

```
@Service
public class Myservice(){

    @Autowired Myrepo1 myrepo1;
    @Autowired Myrepo2 myrepo2;

      public void service1() {
          myrepo1.findBy...
          myrepo2.findBy...
      }
}
```

I think that there isn't another variant...

**UPDATE**

If the goal is to have a kind of 'clean code' I can propose a kind of approach:

```
public interface MyRepo1 extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Long> {
}

public interface MyRepo2 extends JpaRepository<Entity2, Long> {
}

@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class RepoContainer {

    private final MyRepo1 myRepo1;
    private final MyRepo2 myRepo2;  
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MyService() {

    private final RepoContainer repoContainer;

    public void method() {
        repoContainer.getMyRepo1().findBy(...);
        repoContainer.getMyRepo2().findBy(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read my question, it is not about discovering nested repositories...

Comment: My goal is to have a clean code in `MyService` class, but I think there isn't another way.

Comment: I don't understand the middle code, `RepoContainer` is a class or a constructor?

Comment: @akuma8 `Getter` and `RequiredArgsConstructor` it's a Lombok annotations

Comment: I usually use @Getter above class fields that is why I was confused. Could you separate each section of code and adding the wrapper class? and Adding the `@Autowired`

Comment: @akuma8 what do you mean 'separate each section'? There are two interfaces and two classes in my code. All is quite simple...

Comment: Separate like my first post, as if each section of code was in a different file. To make it more readable, and add the wrapper class of the 2 interfaces.

Comment: @akuma8 I'm sure you can do it yourself in your project )

Comment: I already found a solution which works perfectly but I would compare whith yours if it is the same, so I can accept your response otherwise I will put my response. And posting code in stackoverflow should be readable.

Comment: Sure I posted it

Answer (score 0):

I support @Cepr0 answer,
To reduce your code, you don't have to separate your entities from Repositories interfaces, combine them in one class as follows:-

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity{
//.....

  @Repository
  public static interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<MyEntity,String>{

  }
}
```

then

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class Application {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@akuma8 your code can be refactored to remove the extra inner container

```
@Component
public class RepositoryContainer(){

  @Repository
  public interface Myrepo1 extends JpaRepository<Entity1, Long> {
  }
  @Repository
  public interface Myrepo2 extends JpaRepository<Entity2, Long> {
  }

  public final Myrepo1 repo1;

  public final Myrepo2 repo2;

  @Autowired
  public RepositoryContainer(Myrepo1 repo1, Myrepo2 repo2) {
    this.repo1 = repo1;
    this.repo2 = repo2;
  } 

}
```